# For Children, For Teens, For Adults

Tags: riddle, word

- For children, I am a game.
- For teens, I am a reference.
- For adults, I am a price.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you might be the word:

> **TAG**

*For children, I am a game.*

> **[Tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(game))** is a children's playground *game*, also known as 'tig' or 'it', depending on where you live.

*For teens, I am reference.*

> Teens tend to be prolific users of social media. A [**hashtag**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag) is a way to *reference* subjects and themes of interest on many networks, including Twitter and Facebook.

*For adults, I am a price.*

> A [**price tag**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/price_tag) is a label on a product that shows a shopper (commonly an adult) what its *price* is.

Answer (score 1):

This kinda fits too

> A textbook

For children, I am a game.

> Children don't understand complicated sentences.

For teens, I am reference.

> Cause writing an "informed essay" is a must

For adults, I am a price

> We're getting scammed

Answer (score 0):

For a child,

> tag is a game.

For a teenager,

> a tag is one's personal mark used in graffiti.

For adults,

> a tag indicates price.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably...

> The internet!

> Kids play online games; 
>  Teens use this for reference; 
>  And adults pay for this, but here it's slow and costly.

Comment: Gee, thanks for that!